# How to run code after constructor in a Lombok builder

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class that I want to use Lombok.Builder and I need pre-process of some parameters. Something like this:

```
@Builder
public class Foo {
   public String val1;
   public int val2;
   public List<String> listValues;

   public void init(){
       // do some checks with the values.
   }
}
```

normally I would just call `init()` on a NoArg constructor, but with the generated builder I'm unable to do so. Is there a way for this `init` be called by the generated builder? For example `build()` would generate a code like:

```
public Foo build() {
   Foo foo = Foo(params....)
   foo.init();
   return foo;
}
```

I'm aware that I can manually code the `all args` constructor, that the Builder will call through it and I can call `init` inside there.

But that is a sub-optimal solution as my class will likely have new fields added every once in a while which would mean changing the constructor too.

Answer (score 22):

In `Foo` you could manually add a constructor, have that do the initialization, and put `@Builder` on the constructor. I know that you already know this, but I think it is the right solution, and you won't forget to add the parameter since you do want to use the code in the builder anyway.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: hi Roel, I'm happy you stopped by to answer. Thanks for the lib. If I create my own constructor, that means I'll have to manually create an "all-arg" constructor and maintain it every time there're new fields. Searching more I found this feature request on the lib https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/674 and I guess that is really what I wanted.

Comment: Overriding build() is ok for classes with a handful of fields. But for any complex dto, this becomes really painful to maintain.  It's even worse if the fields have string or primitives - if the field order in the constructor gets changed, it's a disaster.

Comment: You saved my day @Roel Spilker

Answer (score 18):

After much trial and end error I found a suitable solution: extend the generate builder and call `init()` myself.

Example:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true, builderClassName = "FooInternalBuilder", builderMethodName = "internalBuilder")
public class Foo {

   public String val1;
   public int val2;
   @Singular public List<String> listValues;

   void init() {
      // perform values initialisation
   }

   public static Builder builder() {
      return new Builder();
   }

   public static class Builder extends FooInternalBuilder {

      Builder() {
         super();
      }

      @Override public Foo build() {
         Foo foo = super.build();
         foo.init();
         return foo;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it doesn't work very well with `toBuilder()` but the rest is fine.

Comment: You don't need to provide the `builderClassname`. If you have class `FooBuilder` in your code, lombok will just add the methods to that class.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll do some test and check it out.

Comment: Really interesting implementation. Thanks. Since the whole idea is to supplement the builder shouldnt init() be defined as part of Builder?

Comment: The builder class should be private IMHO, as you are creating it using builder.
I would try to set the builder with access level package, to avoid creation of the parent builder.

From Lombok documentation:
@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE) is legal (and will generate the builder class, the builder method, etc with the indicated access level) starting with lombok v1.18.8.

Comment: @Budius this is great! Saves you from calling all the arguments in build if you were to implement the build method yourself and plays well with `@Builder.Default`

Comment: I was excited about this approach, but after testing I see that it doesn't work with toBuilder or @jacksonized.  I think the only fix is going to come from an extension of Lombok...

Comment: why do we even need `builderMethodName`? we don't seem to be using it

Answer (score 12):

I just stumbled upon the same issue. But additionally, I wanted to add an method `buildOptional()` to the builder to not repeat `Optional.of(Foo)` each time I need it. This did not work with the approach posted before because the chained methods return `FooInternalBuilder` objects; and putting `buildOptional()` into `FooInternalBuilder` would miss the `init()` method execution in `Builder`...

Also, I personally did not like the presence of 2 builder classes.

Here is what I did instead:

```
@Builder(buildMethodName = "buildInternal")
@ToString
public class Foo {
    public String val1;
    public int val2;
    @Singular  public List<String> listValues;

    public void init(){
        // do some checks with the values.
    }    

    /** Add some functionality to the generated builder class */
    public static class FooBuilder {
        public Optional<Foo> buildOptional() {
            return Optional.of(this.build());
        }

        public Foo build() {
            Foo foo = this.buildInternal();
            foo.init();
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do a quick test with this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = Foo.builder().val1("String").val2(14)
            .listValue("1").listValue("2").build();
    System.out.println(foo);

    Optional<Foo> fooOpt = Foo.builder().val1("String").val2(14)
            .listValue("1").listValue("2").buildOptional();
    System.out.println(fooOpt);
}
```

Doing so let's you add what I want:

- Add an `init()` method which is executed after each object construction automatically
- Adding new fields do not require additional work (as it would be for an individually written constructor)
- Possibility to add additional functionality (incl. the `init()` execution)
- Retain the complete
  standard functionality the `@Builder` annotation brings
- Don't expose an additional builder class

Even if you solved your problem before I like to share this as the solution. It is a bit shorter and adds a (for me) nice feature.

Comment: You expose here a build internal, which is not actually internal

Comment: @DavidBarda : I indeed want to expose `build()` and `buildOptional()` (as a convenience method) because both functions might be used throughout the code.
Or do you mean something different?

Comment: What about exposing the buildInternal() method?

Comment: @DavidBarda: Ah, OK. This is a (very) small price I am willing to pay for the generic approach. I agree that it's not 100% ideal but the usage of the Builder is as how one would expect it: using the `build()` method to get the object.
Me personally, I see "internal" as a warning to not use the method. Of course we could rename it but getting a downvote for a different opinion on naming is quite hard (to me).

Comment: Here's what I did:
1. Renamed buildInternal to buildInitial
2. Change return type for init from void to Foo
3. Change method body of build to just: return this.buildInitial().init();

Not much difference, just a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me, not a complete solution, but quick and easy.

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
   @Builder.Default
   int bar = 42;
   Foo init() {
      // perform values initialisation
     bar = 451;   // replaces 314
     return foo;
   }
   static Foo test() {
       return new FooBuilder()  // defaults to 42
           .bar(314)  // replaces 42 with 314
           .build()
           .init();   // replaces 314 with 451
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution but not optimal as the user need to remember to call the method init each time it will use the builder which is error prone.

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation, it is quick and easy, and the same solution as the top rated one here, in essence