# Lombok return custom build object in builder

Tags: java, java-8, lombok

I've a class which I don't have the ability to modify but would like to have a builder for it. I'm using Lombok.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class SampleClass {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

To have a builder for this, I create a BuilderClass:

```
@Builder
public class SampleClassBuilder {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    public SampleClass build() {
        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
        sampleClass.setA(x + "testX");
        sampleClass.setB(y + "textY");
        return sampleClass;
    }
}
```

To use it, I will need to do:

```
SampleClass sampleClass = SampleClassBuilder.builder().x("x -- ").y("y---").build().build();
```

Is there a way to override build method to return SampleClass to avoid doing build.build?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Lombok can do this: return another object from Builder. It even cannot call super in the builder.

Probably you could define your own build not using Lombok:

```
public class SampleBuilder {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    public static SampleBuilder builder() {
        return new SampleBuilder();
    }

    private SampleBuilder() {
    }

    public SampleBuilder x(String x) {
        this.x = x;
        return this;
    }

    public SampleBuilder y(String y) {
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }

    public SampleClass build() {
        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
        sampleClass.setA(x + "testX");
        sampleClass.setB(y + "textY");
        return sampleClass;
    }
}
```

And in your client code, you can see `Lombok's like` usage of builder:

```
SampleClass obj = SampleBuilder.builder().x("x").y("y").build();
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of writing a custom builder like how you mentioned, but wanted to know if there was any alternate way with Lombok. Guess I'll have to go with this option.

Comment: Anfortunately, Lombok is not so smart. It can do some very common tasks.

Comment: Yeah. The closest I got to was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968696/how-to-run-code-after-constructor-in-a-lombok-builder But then I can't change the return type while overriding

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to have custom builder's setters (like `.x(...)` `.y(...)` but not custom `.build()`), you can just add `SampleClassBuilder` as static inner class to override some Lombok setter methods.

```
@Builder // <--- Put @Builder at the SampleClass itself, not at Builder class
@ToString
class SampleClass { // Lombok will internally create SampleClassBuilder

    private String x;
    private String y;
    private int a,b,c;
    private String z;

    public static class SampleClassBuilder{ // Need to name like this to override Lombok class
        public SampleClassBuilder x(String x){
            this.x = x + "testX"; // Lombok will also create `this.x` for this builder class (also y,a,b,c,z)
            return this;
        }
        public SampleClassBuilder y(String y){
            this.y = y + "testY";
            return this;
        }
        public SampleClassBuilder z(String z){
            this.z = this.x + this.y; // *`.z()` must be called lastly if refer to other fields
            return this;
        }
    }
```

To use it, you can simply do this:

```
SampleClass sample = SampleClass.builder().x("One").z(null).y("Two").a(1).b(2).c(3).build();
System.out.println(sample); // SampleClass(x=OnetestX, y=TwotestY, a=1, b=2, c=3, z=OnetestXnull)
```

*Please note that using this pattern, `.z(...)` needs to be called after others; otherwise, the value will be wrong as `z`="OnetestX**null**" because `y` is `null` at that time.

To overcome this issue:

- You can append `this.z(null)` into method `x()` and `y()`
- Or, use another pattern here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773183/2710335 to avoid putting `this.z(null)` everywhere (Eg. `this.z = this.x + this.y + this.a + this.b + this.c + ...;`).