# Can I use the Lombok @Builder passing the parent class as parameter?

Tags: java, lombok

I want to create a new `Child` instance passing a `Parent` and other additional parameters.

For example if I have:

```
public class Parent {
    public String param1;
    public String param2;
    // many parameters
    public String paramN;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public String subValue;
}
```

With lombok, is there a builder that lets me create a `Child` instance passing the `Parent` and the missing value as parameters?

Would be easier if I could write something like:

```
Parent p = Parent.builder()
                 .param1("a")
                 .param2("b")
                 // many parameters
                 .paramN("b")
                 .build();
Child c = Child.builder(p).subValue("c").build();
```

Comment: why don't you prefer option of creating child in one go something like Child c = Child.builder()..name("a").value("b").subValue("c").build(); with help of @SuperBuilder

Comment: @ShaileshChandra well, in the real case the parent has really a big number of fields. In this way would not be easier...

Comment: understood then I would suggest go for composition instead of inheritance , what do you think, and you can have a field named with parent of parent type

Comment: @ShaileshChandra the composition is not what I was looking for :)

Comment: ok, however lf we talk about lombok it only generates the code during compilation, just think if lombok decides to offer this what code it will be generate ?

Answer (score 6):

The regular `@Builder` is not sufficient here, because you are dealing with a class hierarchy. However, `@SuperBuilder` was made exactly for such a case.

`@SuperBuilder` generates complex code loaded with generics. That makes this solution difficult to understand without in-depth knowledge about the code `@SuperBuilder` generates. You should think about whether this is worth it.

Here's the solution (with Lombok >= 1.18.16):

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public static class Parent {
    public String param1;
    public String param2;
    // many parameters
    public String paramN;

    public abstract static class ParentBuilder<C extends Parent, B extends Parent.ParentBuilder<C, B>> {
        protected B $fillValuesFromParent(Parent instance) {
            $fillValuesFromInstanceIntoBuilder(instance, this);
            return self();
        }
    }
}

@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public static class Child extends Parent {
    public String subValue;

    public static ChildBuilder<?, ?> toBuilder(Parent p) {
        return new ChildBuilderImpl().$fillValuesFromParent(p);
    }
}
```

The new `toBuilder` method on `Child` creates a new `ChildBuilderImpl` (which will create a `Child` instance when calling `build()`). To fill the values from the given `Parent p`, it calls the new `$fillValuesFromParent` method from `ParentBuilder`. This method further delegates the call to the method `$fillValuesFromInstanceIntoBuilder`, which is generated by Lombok and performs the actual copying of the field values to the new builder instance.

Also note the `$` prefix on the methods. This basically says: I'm an implementation detail; don't use me unless you know what you are doing, I might break on the next Lombok version without further notice.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers don't truly make your client code simply reuse the parent instance you already have. But this is doable. You have two options:

The hard one is to write your custom annotation that does what you want. You can even make it generic so that it works for any classes the have parent/child hierarchy. Have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok). If you feel brave you can raise a feature request on [Lombok's github](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok) page.

Option two would be to write your custom builder for the child. See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968696/how-to-run-code-after-constructor-in-a-lombok-builder). In your custom builder in the init step you would be reading a passed in Parent instance, and setup the inherited fields only.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Even if I have upvoted this, the option two points to a question with many answers, it is not clear what answer is the example are you referring to. Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Have found simple workaround. You will need **@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)** annotation in parent and child classes. SuperBuilder provides constructor with builder class as a parameter, so we can use it in child class for doing a copy. This means that you don't need to write mapping manually at all.

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Parent {

   private String field;

}

@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Child extends Parent {

    private String extraField;

    public Child(Parent instance) {
        super(instance.toBuilder());
    }

    public static ChildBuilder<?, ?> builder(Parent instance) {
        return new Child(instance).toBuilder();
    }
}
```

As a result you can copy fields from parent instance to child builder and supplement with needed data:

```
Child result = Child.builder(parentInstance)
                .extraField("extra")
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. which version of lombok should I use?

Comment: @freedev Good question, I've used 1.18.10. According to documentation [link](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder), 
`@SuperBuilder` was introduced as experimental feature in lombok v1.18.2.
`@SuperBuilder's toBuilder` feature was added with lombok v1.18.4. So the minimum version should be 1.18.4

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that could be useful for those following this thread is to utilize a mapping library like MapperStruct. With MapperStruct, you can define a mapper interface as follows:

```
@Mapper
public interface PetMapper {
   Dog toDog(Pet pet);
}
```

After defining the mapper, you can use it in your code like this:

```
private static final PetMapper mapper;

...

public void myFunction(Pet pet) {
    mapper.toDog(pet).toBuilder().id("My ID").build();
}
```

or

```
private static final PetMapper mapper;

...

public void myFunction(Pet pet) {
    mapper.toDog(pet).setId("My ID");
}
```

This way, you can easily map between different objects and modify the resulting object as needed.

## Update

The idea here is to let the mapper handle the creation of a new object child from the parent class (or from its sibling classes), and then using that mapped object you can use its setters to set custom properties or you can use toBuilder() (Be aware that the toBuilder will create a new object once you call .build()).

Comment: Hi Rui, interesting suggestion but not very clear could you please elaborate better?

Comment: And... ideally I don't want modify objects but create a new ones.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @freedev The code creates a new object Dog from Pet and then uses the builder to make a new object Dog with the Id specified.
That is a little annoying since it creates an object pet which is merely a middle state, which is unnecessary. To remedy this, you can utilize the sets methods from the dog class, so this code `mapper.toDog(pet).mapper.toDog(pet)setId("My ID");` would be `mapper.toBuilder().id("My ID");`